# Magento 2 admin in invoice total section grand total not get reduced

Tags: magento2, php, grand-total, create-invoice, store-credit

When creating an invoice for the order from Magento 2 admin panel, the grand total not get reduced with my store credit value.

[image]

Comment: did you find any solutions, Can you post it ?